# windows defender create a workflow based on scan result

Tags: windows, powershell, api, antivirus, powershell-cmdlet

I want to run windows defender on a folder and based on the scanresult for each file ('infected' or 'healthy'), move the file to different folders. I am aware of powershells defender cmdlets. Seems like while running Start-MpScan, the function doesnt give much output about the scanresult?

Is there any API related to windows defender og powershell cmdlet which gives more control over the scan prosess in terms of getting hold of the scan result and based on that do different tasks?

Thanks

Comment: I might suggest opening Event Viewer (eventvwr.msc), visit Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Windows Defender > Operational log, locate the event IDs you'd like to respond to, right-click on them, and select "Attach Task to This Event..." from the context menu.  This will setup event-driven tasks allowing you to run your PowerShell scripts when various Windows Defender conditions arise.  Keep in mind, when Windows Defender detects malware, it should move the file to its Quarantine folder.  Worth a mention.

Comment: You can do this using windows defender function. This is my sample source. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64061445/how-can-i-remove-threat-using-windows-defender-functions

Comment: But i also have problem. I did not find threat remove function.